# Draw lines on UITextView and align the text accordingly

Tags: iphone, uitextview

How can i draw lines on UITextView and set text accordingly. I got this idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072153/how-to-make-uitextview-background-lines-aligned-with-the-text) link. But not clear how to implement this thing. I don't have much experience in this.
Please guide for above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: means you want border of textview?

Comment: @DhavalBhadania No i want lines like in a notebook.

Answer (score 0):

It uses NSLayoutManagerDelegate, that is used in ios7. For iOS 7, the styleString approach no longer works. You have to use NSLayoutManagerDelegate, it is easy to use. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview).

Comment: In this you can use background image not to draw lines yourself. I did with image.