# UILabel taking a long time to render non-english NSAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` attached to a `UIScrollView`. 
The `Label` is getting its `attributed text` from a `.rtf(Rich Text File)`. The code I'm using to achieve this is:

```
    string =
    [NSAttributedString.alloc
     initWithFileURL:[ NSBundle.mainBundle URLForResource:@"fileName" withExtension:@"rtf"  ]
     options:nil
     documentAttributes:nil
     error:NULL
     ];
```

I am then passing the "`string`"(`attributedString`) to my `UILabel` like so

```
[self.Label setAttributedText:string];
self.Label.numberOfLines = 0;
self.Label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.Label.font = [self.Label.font fontWithSize:(long)fontSize];
```

This all takes place in the **ViewDidLoad**.

My problem is that it takes a very long time to process this line:     `[self.Label setAttributedText:string];`
Switching from one view to this view can take seconds.

Furthermore, when I try to change the font of the `self.Label` it takes a very long time as well.

I know the problem is with the `UILabel` processing the `attributedString` I'm just not sure why and how to fix it.

**Important Note**: *The easy answer is use a `UITextView`, I don't want to because scrolling long non-english text in a `UITextView` is choppy and slow. Users have complained about it and after much research I've concluded that `UILabel` in a `scrollView` is the only way to achieve smooth scrolling for this application*.

Comment: Have you tried CoreText + NSAttributedString?

Comment: @NightFury how is that done can you explain

Comment: See [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app) tutorial and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768801/can-i-use-nsattributedstring-in-core-text-in-ios) post. Hope it helps!